# How can I combine Umbraco with a CDN?

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco, cdn

I want to know how I can combine an Umbraco site with a CDN.

For example, when a user is in the back-end and wants to upload a video, the video is uploaded to a CDN.

Any feedback would be great!

Versions: 4 and 6

Comment: You probably need to write an backend extension, so the actual question is *"How to write an umbraco backend extension?"*, which is definitely too general to be answered in here. You should at least provide information about [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/).

Comment: Agree that it is a bit too broad and unspecific but not off topic.

Answer (score 3):

You can of course build this yourself, but also there are some packages that can help you achieve this:

1. [universal media picker 1.5](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/universal-media-picker) works with v4 and v6 and is currently retired 2018-07
2. [Amazon S3 Datatype](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/amazon-s3-datatype) may work with 6.1 and 7.4

The first one can connect to quite a few different CDN's.

#### 3rd party edit 2018-07

I have not tested [azure cdn toolkit for umbraco](https://our.umbraco.com/projects/developer-tools/azure-cdn-toolkit-for-umbraco/) but it is tested for 7.7 (100%) and may be worth a try.